# php + mysql: finding all rows that contain string "ABC" in some field

Tags: php, mysql, indexing

I'm relatively new to this stuff, so forgive if the question is dump. Suppose a table with fields: id, str_field. values of str_field is something like "12:17:1246:90". I want to get all rows where str_field contains e.g. "17". To do this I'll need to execute the following command

```
SELECT id FROM `table_name` WHERE INSTR(str_field, '17')>0
```

If there's a large number of rows in the table the query can be slow. Here's the question: if I'll index str_field will it increase the spead of query execution?

Thank you in advance!

**PS**. In other terms I'm asking: does index increase the spead on for the queries like

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE str_field='value'
```

?

**UPD** str_field contains only numbers separated by colons.

Comment: Does the field have a fixed format, such as four small numbers separated by colons? Or can it contain arbitrary text including letters and symbols? If the field contains "172" should "17" match it?

Comment: Just numbers separated by colons

Comment: Is there any limit on the size of the numbers? Is there any limit on the number of numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a fulltext index and use the special MATCH functionality: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Still, searching for values instead of expressions is much faster...

Comment: Yes, I understand that searching values is faster.. Still, that's not my case

Answer (score 5):

> If there's a large number of rows in the table the query can be slow. Here's the question: if I'll index str_field will it increase the spead of query execution?

Not much. If there are many other columns in your table then you can make a covering index on the columns you use: `(id, str_field)`. This will be slightly faster because the index will be smaller than the original table and therefore can be read faster. However it will still require a full scan of the index (instead of a full scan of the entire table).

But other than that, you can improve the speed of the query by using a separate table with three columns to store the separate integers, using an approach called [denormalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization).

```
parent   sortorder   value
1        1           12
1        2           17
1        3           1246
1        4           90
```

Query like this:

```
SELECT parent AS id
FROM table_values
WHERE `value` = 17
```

You can then add an index on `(value, parent)` for this table, which will speed up the query. Note that the `sortorder` column is not required for this query. If you don't think you will ever need it then you don't need to include this column in your table.

Comment: There can be arbitrary number of colons in `field_str` so I can't store integers in separate columns

Comment: He was suggesting placing each integer in a separate row, not a separate column.  Searching on any type of delimited data in a database column is horribly inefficient.

Answer (score 2):

Indexes can increase perfomance, that is true.

If you have a field which contains string data like `12:17:1246:90`, you can use the query

```
SELECT id FROM `table_name` WHERE `str_field` LIKE '%17%';
```

`%` is the a joker character which means *one or more characters*.

Comment: Will it be faster then using `INSTR(str_field, '17')>0`?

Comment: I think yes, as `instr` returns a value where the string searched for starts, while the statement I ran only checks for existance. But I don't think the performance impact would be that big between the two commands. I will try some tests on my local machine.

Comment: Actually that query would include rows where `str_field` has a value like `12:4179:1246:90`.

Comment: @Kjir Affirmative. Just like how the query Eugeny89 uses does, too. Using `INSTR(str_field, '17')>0` or `str_field LIKE '%17%'` is equivalent in terms of the result fetched.

Comment: True, but still I think it's not what is intended. although only Eugeny89 knows what's really needed...

Comment: I have the same feeling, too. If he/she wishes to search for the exact number present, it will be a bit harder approach. Might wish to store the number of arrays `serialize()`d and read the array and check inside with array functions.